# I want to create a js file and have to load img tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function loadApp(){

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/bmw-918407_1280.jpg";
    src.appendChild(img);

}
window.onload = loadApp;
```

create a loadApp function that runs when your document is loaded. Inside   the   loadApp   function, I   want   you   to   call   a   function: createImage(“images/imageName.png").

how to do this ?

Comment: Does it matter with jQuery?

Comment: no we have to make a function in js file and load the img from there.

Answer (score 1):

You need also parent item selector.

```
// parentSelector is the parent of your image element. Pass the parameter whatever you want.
// imgSource is the URL of your image. Make sure it's appropriate image link (not broken)
function createAndPush(parentSelector, imgSource){
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', imgSource);
    img.appendTo(parentSelector)
}

// Call in the onLoad or document ready.
createAndPush('#footer', 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45')
```

Calling function in jQuery onReady as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   createAndPush('#footer', 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45')
})
```

**Here is the Code Snippet**

```js
// parentSelector is the parent of your image element. Pass the parameter whatever you want.
// imgSource is the URL of your image. Make sure it's appropriate image link (not broken)
function createAndPush(parentSelector, imgSource){
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', imgSource);
    img.appendTo(parentSelector)
}


$(document).ready(function(){
   createAndPush('#footer', 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
window.onload= e => document.body.innerHTML
    += '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/630/150/">';
```

Comment: It looks elegant. Just like JS genious :)

Answer (score 0):

For example like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    function addImage(src){
        var newimg = document.createElement("img");
        newimg.setAttribute("src", src);
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(newimg);
    } 
    window.onload = addImage("images/bmw-918407_1280.jpg");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does work. Why are you saying so? Are you receiving any error in the console? How are you using this code?

Answer (score 0):

This is your javascript file below.  Include it before the  tag in your HTML

```
function loadApp(){
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "images/bmw-918407_1280.jpg";
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);
}

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    loadApp();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is asynchronous downloading. It should download image every 3 seconds.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (4 == xmlhttp.readyState) {
if (xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 300) {
      xmlhttp.open('GET', downloadUrl, true);
      xmlhttp.responseType = 'blob';
  } else {
      console.log("http error: " + xmlhttp.status);
  }
}
};
xmlhttp.timeout = 3000;
```